# Cannot get all the document inside sub collection inside firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection name items, with document named after the uid and inside it there is another collection post which have autogenerated document and data. I am trying to query and get all the collection inside post.

```
<pre>

    <script>
      function show_items(){
       var u_id;
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        u_id=user.uid;
        console.log(u_id);
      } else {
        return;
      }
    });
        var outputlist=[];
        var dbs=firebase.firestore();
        dbs.collection('items').doc(u_id).collection('post').get().
        then(querySnapshot => {
          console.log(querySnapshot.size);
         if (querySnapshot.empty) {
           console.log('No matching documents.');
         }
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, '=>',doc.data());
            outputList.push(doc.data());
          });
        })
          .catch(err => {
          console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        });
      }
    </script>

</pre>
```

Firestore rules:
[image: Firestore rules]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the query to the database runs before the `u_id=user.uid` line is every executed.

Since refreshing the user's authentication state may take some time, it is an asynchronous operation. Once that operation completes, your callback is executed and set the `u_id` variable. But by that time you've already queried the database with the wrong `u_id` value.

For this reason any code that needs the UID of the user, needs too be inside the callback that is executed when that UID is available.

So something like this:

```
function show_items(){
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      var outputlist=[];
      var dbs=firebase.firestore();
      dbs.collection('items').doc(user.uid).collection('post').get().
      then(querySnapshot => {
        console.log(querySnapshot.size);
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
        }
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.id, '=>',doc.data());
          outputList.push(doc.data());
        });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, frank it helped me. I stored the uid in session storage instead while login.